# embedding audio into blogger

Tags: audio, blogger

In Blogger I am trying to recreate the audio feature used in this web site http://www.talkenglish.com/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=2001 where you click on text and hear the audio (an mp3 file) instantly. When I embed identical code into a Blogger page and click it, it wants to play the mp3 file by kick starting Windows Media Player. I don't want a solution like SoundCloud that creates visible player controls. Can anyone suggest a solution. I am hoping to use it to create an online amateur speech therapy package to support some voluntary work I do in this area.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site is using a file called audioplayer.js.  To be honest, I am not exactly sure if that's custom built or not.  You can look at the source for that [here](http://www.talkenglish.com/includes/js/audioplayer.js).  You have a bunch of options to get the functionality you're looking for.  A couple are below.

You can use [SoundManager2](http://(function(e)%7Bfunction%20n(t,n)%7Bfunction%20tn(e)%7Breturn%20i.preferFlash&&_t&&!i.ignoreFlash&&i.flash[e]!==undefined&&i.flash[e]%7Dfunction%20nn(e)%7Breturn%20function(t)%7Bvar%20n=this._s,r;if(!n%7C%7C!n._a)%7Bif(n&&n.id)%7Bi._wD(f+%22ignoring%20%22+t.type+%22:%20%22+n.id)%7Delse%7Bi._wD(f+%22ignoring%20%22+t.type)%7Dr=null%7Delse%7Br=e.call(this,t)%7Dreturn%20r%7D%7Dthis.setupOptions=) which is a very robust JS Sound plugin.

You can also use HTML5's built in `<audio>` element.  You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

Comment: Thanks Elliott . The    <audio> option is partly successful. It works where the file type (.mp3) is specified in the src url - but url links to files on Google Drive don't use the file type. Unfortunately I was hoping to use Google Drive to park the generated audio files that I hope to use. Any ideas please?

Comment: I am not sure honestly.  It looks like Google Drive requires a player to play MP3s.  I think you may have a hard time getting a cloud storage service like Drive or Dropbox to do this.  I imagine they work similarly to Soundcloud w/ regards to streaming.  Meaning, they basically spin up a player whenever you need access to them, but don't actually have them ready to be played 24/7.  Unfortunately those services aren't made for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Elliott I found an answer to the Google Drive link issue on stackoverflow here    [link] (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65763/how-can-i-hotlink-an-mp3-in-google-drive-with-a-url-ending-in-mp3)  - thanks for your help